# Branch.io: how to merge events sent server-to-server with user installs reported from the client?

Tags: analytics, branch.io

### The setup

I have an iOS app with a basic Branch SDK integration. All it does is:

- reports the install event (via initSession() call)
- some time later calls setIdentity() method to identify the user with an ID received from backend

Later inside the app the user is offered a subscription with a trial period. The backend receives a notification once the trial is started. I want to report the trial start from my backend to the Branch (server-to-server way) so it is attributed to the Branch channel/campaign and I can see the efficiency of each campaign inside the "Sources" tool in Branch.

To do this I execute the following curl request in accord with the documentation https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#logging-user-lifecycle-events:

```
curl -vvv -d '{"name": "START_TRIAL","customer_event_alias": "Trial Start","user_data": {"os": "iOS","environment": "FULL_APP","aaid":"93A6BC61-AC2B-4008-9565-4DF2FD2395C9","limit_ad_tracking":false,"developer_identity": "41740","country": "US","language": "en"},"custom_data": {"product_id": "my.product.id"},"metadata": {},"branch_key": "key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}' https://api2.branch.io/v2/event/standard
```

The received answer is:
    {"branch_view_enabled":false}

As seen from the request I pass the IDFA and developer_identity and I expect that it would be enough to attribute START_TRIAL event to the Branch channel/campaign, which brought the user.

### The problem

The START_TRIALS and other valuable events are attributed to organic traffic. So for a test campaign I see a click, an install an open but zero trial starts. The trial start is attributed to the organic traffic.

### What I've checked

I've checked with Charless SSL that the user ID is sent by Branch SDK to Branch backend (notice same IDFA **93A6BC61-AC2B-4008-9565-4DF2FD2395C9** and user id **41740**):

> "os": "iOS",
>       "hardware_id": "**93A6BC61-AC2B-4008-9565-4DF2FD2395C9**",
>       "screen_width": 750,
>       "identity_id": "789438365770392069",
>       "build": "16G183",
>       "ios_vendor_id": "A3656BAB-CDF9-4572-B944-80D5B6017376",
>       "hardware_id_type": "idfa",
>       "instrumentation": {
>           "/v1/install-brtt": "406"
>       },
>       "environment": "FULL_APP",
>       "model": "iPhone7,2",
>       "identity": "**41740**",

So given all of the data I already pass to Branch, what else should I do to merge events sent server-to-server with user installs reported from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to track iOS event I guess you should use `user_data.idfa` instead of `user_data.aaid` (Android ID).

From [documentation](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#logging-user-lifecycle-events):

> user_data.aaid : Android/Google advertising id
>
> user_data.idfa : iOS advertising id